# Why is it possible to declare a variable of 'anyTextString' type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, tsc

Why `tsc` doesn't complain for this line of code:

```
let a: 'my text string';
```

and allows `a` to be of type `'my text string'`?

And... Isn't this bug-prone if, let's say, someone takes advantage of implicit type inference, and just puts a `':`' instead of `'='`?!

Comment: This is called literal type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a literal type. The documentation [is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types). An example:

```
type Color = 'blue' | 'red'

function showColor(c: Color) {
  console.log(c)
}

showColor('blue') // OK
showColor('other') // Error
```

Notice: Since TypeScript 2.0, literal types are [expanded to numbers and booleans](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407) (not only strings). Then, with TypeScript 2.1, literal types [are better inferred](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).

---

> And... Isn't this bug-prone if, let's say, someone takes advantage of implicit type inference, and just puts a `':`' instead of `'='`?!

In TypeScript, it's required to spot the `:`. The following code:

```
let a: 'my text string';
```

... is compiled to (here with the target ES6):

```
let a;
```